# VS 2010 & WP8 Device

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i´m developing an XNA application for Windows phone in Visual studio 2010 (SDK 7.1). I´d like to buy a device with WP to test it in real. I wonder if I could run WP7 application on WP8 device (Huawei Ascend W1) in VS 2010.
Thanks

Lukas

Comment: AFAIK there is no problem with this scenario, viceversa is it impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can run any WP7 app in a WP8 device without any problem!

The only situation you could have some problems would be if your app uses FM Radio, as WP8 does not support it.

Comment: Ok. But can I use the WP8 device in VS 2010?

Comment: No, that's not possible. For WP8 devices you'll need VS 2012.

Comment: Correct, you can only debug with a WP8 device with VS2012; but if you install the WP8 SDK, you'll get the VS2012 Express also!

Comment: And one more comment - you can't develop and deploy WP8 device in Windows 7 PC. You mast have a VS 2012 and Windows 8. You can't install WP8 SDK on Windows 7.

Comment: You can install WP8 SDK on Windows 7 (is an informal way), but then you can't use emulator